# Calculate order of multiplicative group of finite field

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, finite-groups, finite-fields

How can one calculate the order of a multiplicative group of a finite field such as:

$(\mathbb{F}(2^3) \backslash \{0\}, \times)$

Is it as simple as doing $2^3-1$ ?

Comment: Yes, the order of $(\Bbb F^{\times},\cdot)$ is the order of the field $\Bbb F$ minus $1$, because we have to take out $0$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks, and unrelated question, are the number of generators the same as the order?

Comment: No, a cyclic group $C_n$ has $1$ generator, but the order is $n$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde $C_n$ has $\varphi(n)$ generators.

Comment: @ChrisCuster ook, so... which of you is right? According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n#Cyclic_case), I think \@Dietrich is right.

Comment: Your link has nothing to do with finite fields (except if $n$ is prime).

Comment: @Bernard Well 7 is a prime

Comment: I beg your pardon, but  your field is $\mathbf F_8$ and it has 8 elements. You seem to be confusing the order of the field and the order of its multiplicative group.  Furthermore, your link is about the units in rings \mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$, which are not necessarily  integral domains.

Comment: @Bernard Oh my mistake, so is \@Chris right?

Comment: Yes. In your case, $\mathbf F_8^\times$ is a cyclic group with $7$ elements, and its generators are $\varphi(7)=6$. In other words any element $\ne 0,1$ is a generator (and it has order $7$ since it is a generator).

Comment: $C_n$ is only generated by one single element, i.e., "it has one generator". This sentence is misleading. Of course we can chose $\phi(n)$ different elements for this one generator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The order of a group is how many elements the group has. Since the multiplicative group of a field is every element except 0 the order of the group is exactly one less than the amount of elements in the field.